# ON DELETE CASCADE doesn't activate trigger

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, mariadb, cascade

I have the following three tables:

- `materials (id, name, ...)`
- `stock_activities (id, material_id, warehouse_id, ..., detail_id)`
- `stock_activity_details (id, title, ...)`

There's a foreign key constaint on the `stock_activities.material_id`, so if a `material` gets deleted, a row that corresponds to the deleted row also gets deleted from the `stock_activities`. So far, so good.

I'm grouping some "stock activities" by using common details, and because I do not want to duplicate these details on each activity row, I store the details on another table, and reference the detail id on the activity rows. This presents a delete problem. I'd like to delete the detail row that's common to multiple activity rows when an activity row is deleted.

I thought about using a trigger (for the first time, I might add) and created the following:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER delete_activity_detail
    AFTER DELETE ON stock_activities FOR EACH ROW
        DELETE FROM stock_activity_details
        WHERE stock_activity_details.id = OLD.detail_id
```

This seems to work if I delete a row from the `stock_activities` table, but does not seem to work if I delete a material. When I delete a material, the foreign key constaint deletes a row from the `stock_activities`, but this delete on `stock_activities` does not seem to activate the trigger (which will delete the activity detail).

Is this the expected behavior? If so, is there a workaround that I can use?

If I can't do this in the database, I'd have to do it manually in the code, but I think it'd be better to handle this in the database.

---

SQL for the test case:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `materials` (
    `id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `stock_activities` (
    `id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `material_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `warehouse_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `detail_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `stock_activities_ibfk_1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`material_id`) REFERENCES `materials` (`id`)
            ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `stock_activity_details` (
    `id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `title` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `materials` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
    (1, 'Foo'),
    (2, 'Bar');

INSERT INTO `stock_activity_details` (`id`, `title`) VALUES
    (1, 'Lorem'),
    (2, 'ipsum');

INSERT INTO `stock_activities` (`material_id`, `detail_id`, `warehouse_id`) VALUES
    (1, 1, 8),
    (2, 2, 9);

CREATE TRIGGER delete_activity_detail
    AFTER DELETE ON stock_activities FOR EACH ROW
        DELETE FROM stock_activity_details
        WHERE stock_activity_details.id = OLD.detail_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

> [MariaDB :: Trigger Limitations](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/trigger-limitations/)
>
> ...
>
> - Triggers are not activated by foreign key actions.
>
> ...

A couple of options that can give you some ideas:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `materials` (
  `id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `stock_activity_details` (
  `id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `title` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `stock_activities` (
  `id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `material_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `warehouse_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `detail_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `stock_activities_ibfk_1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`material_id`) REFERENCES `materials` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `stock_activities_ibfk_2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`detail_id`) REFERENCES `stock_activity_details` (`id`)
      ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Option 1:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER `delete_stock_activities`
BEFORE DELETE ON `materials`
FOR EACH ROW
  DELETE FROM
    `stock_activities`
  WHERE
    `stock_activities`.`material_id` = OLD.`id`;

CREATE TRIGGER `delete_stock_activity_details`
AFTER DELETE ON `stock_activities`
FOR EACH ROW
  DELETE FROM
    `stock_activity_details`
  WHERE
    `stock_activity_details`.`id` = OLD.`detail_id`;
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=d4d923138d1298449587699bb9c52392).

Option 2:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER `delete_stock_activity_details`
BEFORE DELETE ON `materials`
FOR EACH ROW
  DELETE
    `stock_activities`, `stock_activity_details`
  FROM
    `stock_activity_details`
    INNER JOIN `stock_activities` ON
      `stock_activities`.`material_id` = OLD.`id`
  WHERE
    `stock_activity_details`.`id` = `stock_activities`.`detail_id`;
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=8e4dd9248f748d653422d0d34c1e154b).

Comment: Aw, that limitation is a bummer. I think I'll go with the option 2 since it looks more compact.

Comment: @akinuri: Option 2 is more compact, but you lose the functionality to automatically delete rows from `stock_activity_details` when deleting rows from `stock_activities`. Evaluate the trade-offs.

Comment: Haven't made a final decision yet. There's also the "warehouse" factor. Deleting a warehouse should delete the corresponding rows, etc. Not sure how much of the required operations can be done in the database. Might have to add some operations in the code after all. Will give it some thought. But for this "materials" question, your answer  indeed gave some ideas :)

Comment: Now that it occurs to me, I don't think there should be an auto delete on `stock_activity_details` when a row from `stock_activities` is deleted. That's because there isn't a one-to-one relation between the two tables. A delete on `stock_activity_details` should occur only when all the rows from the `stock_activities` that refer to that specific detail row are deleted. As long as there's one activity row that refers to a detail row, the detail row should remain there. Anyway, there're some edge cases, and it seems in-code interventions will be necessary.